# Circumnavigating the Postgres ARRAYField inconvenience in DJANGO 1.9

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Here is the model field:

```
prices = ArrayField(models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2), null=True)...
```

Values:

```
prices': [[Decimal('23.00'), Decimal('38.50')], [Decimal('11.06')], [Decimal('20.00')], [Decimal('3.95')], [Decimal('11.00')], [Decimal('1.77'), Decimal('31.34')], [Decimal('6.62'), Decimal('19.00')], [Decimal('20.60')].....]
```

My aim is to insert into the Postgres DB thusly:

```
models.DasModel.objects.create(
               somedate     = date,
               myprices     = prices,..)
```

I understand Postgres cannot accept such lists into an ArrayField but they must be of the form `{val1, val2,...}`
The error I am getting is

> DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.

Is there an quick and easy way to do the conversion?

Comment: Hi @codervince. Did you already solve this one? I am using ArrayField(JSONField()) and I am getting an exact error like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try using -

```
prices = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)), null=True)...
```

Comment: rationale?I just tried this - nothing doing.
Id rather fit the input to the model rather than the other way round - otherwise Id go for the JSONField and be done with it..